implement in-app pip for both ios and android, for android there npm packages, but for ios i used react native webview
I have to implement in-app pip which can work on both ios and android, npm package is there for pip for android, but for ios I used react native webview and pass video source as uri, it is working fine for iphone 7 device but not working on latest iphones even on emulator.
here is the script and webview code which i used:
 const togglePipMode = () => {
    if (webViewRef.current) {
      console.log("webViewRef.current->", webViewRef.current);
      const script = `
        if (document.pictureInPictureEnabled && !document.pictureInPictureElement) {
          const video = document.querySelector('video');
          if (video) {
            video.requestPictureInPicture();
          }
        }
        document.addEventListener("leavepictureinpicture", function (event) {
          window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("pipExited");
        });
        true`;
      webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(script);
      setPipEnabled(true);
    }
  };
  const removeVideoControls = `
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    if (video) {
      video.style.width = '100%'; 
      video.style.height = 'auto'; 
      video.removeAttribute('controls');
      video.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline', 'true');
      video.setAttribute('playsinline', 'true');
    }
  });
`;

<WebView
                ref={webViewRef}
                source={{
                  uri: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4",
                }}
                androidLayerType={"hardware"}
                style={{ height: SCREEN_HEIGHT, width: SCREEN_WIDTH }}
                allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
                automaticallyAdjustContentInsets
                mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={true}
                allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                mixedContentMode="always"
                injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={removeVideoControls}
                onMessage={(event) => {
                  console.log(
                    "event.nativeEvent.data-->",
                    event.nativeEvent.data
                  );
                  if (event.nativeEvent.data === "pipExited") {
                    handlePipExit();
                  }
                }}
              />

using react-native-webview": "^13.8.1" , react native: 0.63

same question I asked in react-native-webview community https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/172#issuecomment-2048164152, and shared screenshot of the issue as well there, video is being played but it is not taking full space as expected and script is also not being injected i think.
